# js get the highest height of element and set all other element to this height

Tags: javascript

I have a " P Element". So the height of each element can be higher then the other. So I want that all height are the same height, but every the highest.

I get no errors but it not works.

```
    const getHeightAndSetNewHeight = () => {
        const k = document.querySelectorAll('.kamera');
        
        k.forEach(e => {
            if(Math.max(Number(e.offsetHeight))) {
                e.style.height = `${e.offsetHeight}px`;
    
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: `Math.max()` with just one number will just return that same number.

Comment: First get the max height, then set the height of the elements in `k`

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this purpose? 
You can use display: flex to wrapper and justify child elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through once, find the maximum, then loop through again once you have it.

```js
const getHeightAndSetNewHeight = () => {
  const k = document.querySelectorAll('.kamera');
  
  let max = -Infinity;

  k.forEach(e => {
    if (max < e.offsetHeight) max = offsetHeight;
  });
  k.forEach(e => {
    e.style.height = `${e.offsetHeight}px`;
  });
};
```

Comment: He dont set the height €: He set the height but every height has his own. I add a elment and text with appendchild, and the height is 74, I add another element the height is 111px. So the first elemnt has 74px height and the other 111. but all should have 111